# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background parameter specifications

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, slideshow

I've been unable to find out what exactly is the specification of the parameter to be passed to the various org.gnome.desktop.background attributes. Particularly convoluted seems the picture-uri attribute. It seems to accept either the file:// URI of a file to set as the background image, or the file:// URI of an XML file describing a slideshow with rich properties. Those, however, I've not been able to find specified or documented anywhere. All I find are examples of varying quality. For example, what about the "transition" element and its attributes? Some examples mention a "type" attribute for which a valid value may be "fade". Where can I find a specification of all this?

For example, it is unclear how the transition is managed if the picture-uri is used to set an image directly. Can the transition only be controlled when using an XML file? Or can I also set the transition style and duration using some gsettings line?

Comment: **To close voters:** The question is quite clear (at least to me). OP is looking for a specification of wallpaper transition descriptors of GNOME Shell and/or Unity.

Comment: Please always try to add some background on the context of the question, otherwise it's too much for normal Ubuntu users to jump into the very details of gnome background file format specification.

Comment: I've found two values for type attribute of `transition` property. `overlay` and `fade`. But I don't know where those are documented